# How can I use tesseract and opencv to extract the text from the camera

Tags: opencv, ocr, tesseract

I'm using tesseract 3.02 and opencv to let the tesseract recognize the text from my camera realtime.

But the effect is quite bad. Results are unreadable and can't show image fluently. I think it's the problem of my code.

Can some one give me advice about how to modify it?

Thanks a lot!

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <time.h>


using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


int main() {

    // [1]
    tesseract::TessBaseAPI *myOCR = 
            new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();

    // [2]
    printf("Tesseract-ocr version: %s\n",
           myOCR->Version());
    printf("Leptonica version: %s\n",
           getLeptonicaVersion());

    // [3]
    if (myOCR->Init(NULL, "eng")) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Could not initialize tesseract.\n");
      exit(1);
    }

    //声明IplImage指针
    IplImage* pFrame = NULL;

    //获取摄像头
    CvCapture* pCapture = cvCreateCameraCapture(-1);

    //创建窗口
    cvNamedWindow("video", 1);

    //显示视屏
            time_t last_time = time(NULL);
    while(1)
    {

        pFrame=cvQueryFrame( pCapture );
        if(!pFrame)    break;
        cvShowImage("video",pFrame);
        char c=cvWaitKey(33);
        if(c==27)break;

                time_t this_time = time(NULL);
                if(this_time != last_time)
                {
                    last_time = this_time;
        myOCR->SetRectangle(0,0,pFrame->width,pFrame->height);
        myOCR->SetImage((uchar*)pFrame->imageData,pFrame->width,pFrame-   >height,pFrame->depth/8,pFrame->width*(pFrame->depth/8));
        myOCR->Recognize(NULL);
        const char* out = myOCR->GetUTF8Text();
        printf("%s\n",out);
                }

    }
    cvReleaseCapture(&pCapture);
    cvDestroyWindow("video");
    cv::waitKey(-1);
            return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Tesseract was designed to process scanned books. It operates on white pages where there is only black text, clearly seen with minimal distortions. Images are mostly Black & White. Your image is grey level so Tesseract will perform very very poor. 
It is not a problem of your code but of Tesseract.
If you point your camera towards a book, you will be able to get the text (assuming image is focused) but if you want to read general text (like street signs, logo on someones T-shirt than there is no way to do it. Sorry to disappoint you.

However, if you want to recognize a specific text, like credit card numbers or street signs, 
that you can do it.

1. Start by grabbing many imgages of your text.
2. Do a bit of
   pre-processing on the image, convert it to BW,
3. train Tesseract on many examples.

And then it will be able to accomplish your task.

Comment: Thank you for your information. Recognizing text from book is also ok for me. But I'm not only facing the problem of accuracy. Another problem is that it can't show the image smoothly. The delay is very serious. I guess it's probably because I ocr every frame. I want to know how to stablize it? Should I take something like screenshot or what? I just want it to show the text my camera points at. So I guess my code still has some problems

Comment: I understand what you say. You need to

Comment: I understand what you say. You need to run image stabilization algorithm (match consecutive images). From tesseract you can get the boxes (location of each letter on the image). Then you run it once in 1[sec], store the boxes and just draw them according to camera movement

Comment: I've tried that but it doesn't solve the recognition problem. I pointed the camera to a book but it's still unreadable. I will repost my code. Can you help me check if something is wrong? That will be very helpful. Thanks a lot!